# Why is R Shiny throwing this error when plotting data (ggplot2) returned from a reactive() function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm working on a Shiny app that takes input data (csv) from a user, and plots various representations of correlation in the dataset. My scatter plot renders when the user uploads a file, but flashes an error message `Error: no expression to parse` first. It seems that my `ggplot` function is being called before the data being returned from the `reactive()` function is finished uploading, so the input is undefined. Is this because it is executing asynchronously?

I tried adding conditionals to check if the reactive function `getData()` is null before executing the plot, but the error still flashes before successfully rendering the plot.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Correlation Analyzer"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("file", "Choose Clean CSV File to Analyze (must include headers)",
                      accept = c("text/csv","text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv")
            ),
            uiOutput("xvars"), # dropdowns for selecting variable names
            uiOutput("yvars"),
            checkboxGroupInput(inputId='corrType', label="Correlation Type", 
                               choices=c('Continuous - Continuous (Pearson)', "Categorical - Categorical (Kramer's V)", 
                                         'Continuous - Categorical (Correlation Ratio)'), 
                               selected = NULL, inline = FALSE, width = NULL)
        ),
        mainPanel(
            if (is.null(tableOutput("dataHead")) == FALSE) {
                plotOutput("scatter")
            }
        )
    )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

function(input, output) {
    getData = reactive({
        inFile = input$file
        if (is.null(inFile)) {
            return(NULL) 
        }
        df = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
        return(df)
    })

    output$dataHead = renderTable({
        return(head(getData()))
    })
    output$xvars =
        renderUI({ # send list of available variable name choices to UI
            selectInput(inputId='selected_xvar', label="Select X Variable", choices=colnames(getData()), selected=input$selected_xvar)
        })
    output$yvars =
        renderUI({
            selectInput(inputId='selected_yvar', label="Select Y Variable", choices=colnames(getData()), selected=input$selected_yvar)
        })

    output$scatter = renderPlot({
        selected_xvar = input$selected_xvar
        selected_yvar = input$selected_yvar

        df = getData()
        if (is.null(df)==FALSE) {
            ggplot(df, aes_string(x=selected_xvar, y=selected_yvar)) +
                geom_point(shape=1, col="blue") +
                geom_smooth(method=lm) + ggtitle("Scatterplot") + xlab(selected_xvar) + ylab(selected_yvar) +
                theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18, hjust=0.5))

            # plot(unlist(df[selected_xvar]), unlist(df[selected_yvar]), main="Scatterplot", 
            #      xlab=selected_xvar, ylab=selected_yvar, pch=19)
        }
    })
}
```

I also tried using the base `plot()` function, and get an error message `Error: undefined columns selected` before the plot renders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use req() function to stop the process and wait until the variables become available.

```
    if (is.null(df)==FALSE) {
        req(selected_xvar, selected_yvar)
        ggplot(df, aes_string(x=selected_xvar, y=selected_yvar)) + # omitted below
```

See: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html